# ANOVA is significant but post-hoc test not. What next?

Tags: statistics, anova, significance, posthoc

The data consists of weights of fresh harvested plants with four different treatments. The data is normally distributed and homogeneity of variances is given too.

Anova shows significiant differences:

```
anova_Ernte <- aov(Gewicht ~ Variante, data=Daten_Ernte) 
Anova(anova_Ernte)
    


Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: Gewicht
           Sum Sq  Df F value  Pr(>F)  
Variante    57213   3  2.9778 0.03226 *
Residuals 1511436 236                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However post-hoc test HSD.Test() doesnt show any significiant differences:

```
HSD.test(anova_Ernte, "Variante", group = TRUE, console = TRUE, main = "")

4   434.70  a       
1   426.90  a       
3   400.95  a       
2   398.20  a
```

```
    Gewicht std         r   Min Max 
1   426.90  80.08929    80  234 596
2   398.20  79.90095    80  216 561
3   400.95  74.87869    40  228 568
4   434.70  84.98754    40  264 647
```

Tuckey-HSD shows the following

```
TukeyHSD(anova_Ernte)

  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = Gewicht ~ Variante, data = Daten_Ernte)

$Variante
      diff        lwr       upr     p adj
2-1 -28.70 -61.439904  4.039904 0.1085058
3-1 -25.95 -66.048029 14.148029 0.3394912
4-1   7.80 -32.298029 47.898029 0.9582293
3-2   2.75 -37.348029 42.848029 0.9980106
4-2  36.50  -3.598029 76.598029 0.0887876
4-3  33.75 -12.551216 80.051216 0.2368136
```

And finally kurskal wallis does not show significiant differences between the groups:

```
kruskal(y=Daten_Ernte$Gewicht, trt=Daten_Ernte$Variante, p.adj = "bonferroni", console = TRUE)
kruskal.test(Daten_Ernte$Gewicht ~ Daten_Ernte$Variante)

4   133.9000    a       
1   131.2063    a       
3   109.8875    a       
2   108.4000    a
```

Am i now safe to say that there are no significiant differences between the groups or do i have options to find out which groups differ according to anova?

Comment: I think the answer to this question is answered on [this side](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16665/how-can-i-get-a-significant-overall-anova-but-no-significant-pairwise-difference) It is apparently due to the power and sensitivity of the tests when the null hypothesis is rejected as far as i understood.

Comment: actually, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352583/r-tukey-hsd-anova-anova-significant-tukey-not/352603#352603) it is explained properly and clear